# JavaScript regex add space for each item in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have this regex that detects certain character and adds space before or after that character so that I can use `.split(" ")` to store them in an array. Is there a simplified form for this regex?

> 2*5--4/2 = 2 * 5 - -4 / 2
>
> ((1+5)*2/1) = ( ( 1 + 5 ) * 2 / 1 )

```
var infix = $input.val()
                .replace(/(\-\d+)(-)/g, "$1 $2 ")
                .replace(/(\-)(\-\d+)/g, " $1 $2")
                .replace(/([+/*^()])/g, " $1 ")
                .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
```

Comment: Why do you use `[-]` or `\-` instead of just `-`? You only have to escape it inside classes (except edges).

Comment: thanks for the tip sir :)

Comment: Why the extraneous parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to add spaces, so you can then split on them. Instead. you could split directly into an array, using the version of split that retains the splitting characters (by enclosing them in a group). For the splitting regexp, specify either a sequence of digits (with optional leading minus sign), or nothing. This will result in extra blank strings, so remove them with a filter.

```
function split(s) {
  var number_or_nothing = /(-?[\d.]+|)/;
  function non_empty(x) { return /\S/.test(x); }

  return s.split(number_or_nothing) . filter(non_empty);
}

> split("2*5--4/2")
< ["2", "*", "5", "-", "-4", "/", "2"]

> split("((1+5)*2/1)")
< ["(", "(", "1", "+", "5", ")", "*", "2", "/", "1", ")"]
```

Comment: as I test it. `2-2` returns `["2", "-2"]` but the expected result is `["2", "-", "2"]`

Comment: Fixed to accept decimal numbers. I will make the other change soon.

Comment: good day sir, is tokenizer  will yield better result compared to regex?